# How to know the processors last running time in NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

i'm having group of processors to perform some functionalities.

I have scheduled the starting processor to be run upon daily at particular time by using cron expression.

I need to know that the processors last running time.

just consider an example if i having getfile,generateflowfile processor triggers entire workflow by cron. At some times, i enter into that workflow not able to ensure that processor running as per cron or not because it entire processing completed at that time.

can anyone suggest me the best way to ensure the processors last running time and its processing attributes?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Data Provenance` for that. Say for example, you want to see the trigger time for `GenerateFlowFile`. Right click on that processor and select `Data Provenance`, it will list down the provenance stats for the processor.

`Date/Time` column lists the time the processor triggered/created the flowfile. `Type` column refers to the type of the event. `GenerateFlowFile` will always have the type `CREATE` since it just generates the flowfile. Other processors might have different type of events like `DROP`, `ATTRIBUTES_MODIFIED`. However, if you just want to know when the processor gets triggered, look for `CREATE` event type.

[image]